# How to solve StringConverter ClassCast Exception?

Tags: java, string, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a `TableView` and a form with some `TextBox` and `ComboBox` in my javafx application. I am trying to populate the form components with selected rows data from `TableView`. I can populate all the `TextBox` without any error or exception. But while setting values to `ComboBox`es, it's throwing an `ClassCastException`, `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to entity.StockUOM`.

This is my `StringCoverter`

```
    unitCombo.setConverter(new StringConverter<StockUOM>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(StockUOM object) {
            return object.getStockUOM();
        }

        @Override
        public StockUOM fromString(String string) {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

This is my `entity.StockUOM` class

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = StockUOM.findStockUOM, query = "SELECT s from StockUOM s")
})
public class StockUOM implements Externalizable{
public final static String PREFIX = "entity.StockUOM.";
public final static String findStockUOM = PREFIX + "findStockUOM";
private IntegerProperty id;
private int _id;
private StringProperty stockUOM;
private String _stockUOM;

public StockUOM() {
    if (id == null) {
        id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "id", _id);
    }
    if( stockUOM== null){
        stockUOM= new SimpleStringProperty(this,"stockUOM",_stockUOM);
    }
}

public StockUOM(String stockUOM) {
    this();
    this.stockUOM.set(stockUOM);
}

public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
    if (id == null) {
        id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "id", _id);;
    }  
    return id;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public final int getId() {
    if (id == null) {
        return _id;
    } else {
        return id.get();
    }
}

public final void setId(int id) {
    if (this.id == null) {
        _id = id;
    } else {
        this.id.set(id);
    }
}

public StringProperty stockUOMProperty() {
    if( stockUOM== null){
        stockUOM= new SimpleStringProperty(this,"stockUOM",_stockUOM);
    }
    return stockUOM;
}

public final String getStockUOM() {
    if(stockUOM == null){
        return _stockUOM;
    }else{
        return stockUOM.get();
    }
}

public void setStockUOM(String stockUOM) {
    if (this.stockUOM == null) {
        _stockUOM=stockUOM ;
    } else {
        this.stockUOM.set(stockUOM);
    }
}

@Override
public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
   out.writeInt(getId());
   out.writeChars(getStockUOM());
}

@Override
public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    setId(in.readInt());
    setStockUOM((String)in.readObject());
}

@Override
public String toString() {
return getStockUOM();
}
}
```

This is how i am setting values to `ComboBox`

```
unitCombo.setValue(newValue.getUnit());
```

Here `newValue` is the instance of `StockUOM` of `ChangeListner` which is listening on `TableView` row selection.

So what's wrong i am doing ? And what's the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: The first thing to do to fix this is to stop using raw types. I.e. in your controller, don't declare `@FXML private ComboBox unitCombo ;` but `@FXML private ComboBox<SomeType> unitCombo ;`, where `SomeType` is the type of the object displayed in the combo box (probably `StockUOM`). Then (for the most part) the compiler will force you to use the correct types.

Comment: Thank you very much @James_D. This is what i messed up. Actually my `TableView` ( `TableView<Stock>` ) has a different type than `ComboBox` ( `ComboBox<StockUOM>` ) type.  So first i declared the combo box as `ComboBox<StockUOM>` and then in `ChangeListener` of `TableView<Stock>`  i set the `ComboxBox<StockUOM>` value as `unitCombo.setValue(new StockUOM(newValue.getUnit()));` and that's solved my problem. Thank you very much again.

Comment: And that's exactly the same than in my answer yesterday :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that most probably you defined your `ComboBox` like:

```
ComboBox unitCombo = new ComboBox();
```

So you missed to define the generic argument and you ended up with the raw type (your IDE most probably gives you a warning on this line).

At this point it is not specified what kind of objects do you want to display in the `ComboBox`.

When you do the following:

```
unitCombo.setValue(newValue.getUnit());
```

you set the [`valueProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#valueProperty--) as a String value.

And then comes your converter:

```
unitCombo.setConverter(new StringConverter<StockUOM>() {
    @Override
    public String toString(StockUOM object) {
        return object.getStockUOM();
    }

    @Override
    public StockUOM fromString(String string) {
        return null;
    }
});
```

which expects `StockUOM` object being displayed, which does not happen hence the error.

You have to decide what kind of object do you want to display: if it is `StockUOM`, then declare the ComboBox as `ComboBox<StockUOM> unitCombo = new ComboBox<StockUOM>();`. After this you will have a compile time error on the line where you set the value for a String value, to fix that error you have to modify that line as `unitCombo.setValue(newValue);`. If you want to display String objects, the methodology is the same.

Comment: @DVagra i am using fxml. so i am just injecting the combobox in my controller. Even if i declare my combobox as non-fxml component then while setting value as you said like this `unitCombo.setValue(newValue);` , how it will get the specific value from the `StockUOM` as it have more than one value. I have to set an `String` value to  my combo box. This value i have to fetch from an entity class of `TableView` as i mentioned above.

Comment: It is totally unclear what do you want to achieve. The explanation of the problem is described above. What is `newValue.getUnit()`? The value that you want to display? Or? What is exactly `newValue`? Based on the information you provided, the best I can do is to tell you where the problem is coming from.